# How to set format of PDF by PDFsharp, set pagesize to A4 and fit on page (shrink)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdfsharp

I would like to convert image to PDF using PDFsharp in ASP.NET MVC project.
And I have successfully converted them to PDF, but they are in strange format,for example: this image:

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbS4X.jpg)

After conversion with PDFsharp:

[Partially visible image on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Wfl.png)

I hope PDF files can adaptive page, fit on page (shrink),and pagesize is A4.

Below is my code:

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();
doc.PageLayout = PdfPageLayout.OneColumn;

PdfPage pdfPage = new PdfPage();
XSize size = PageSizeConverter.ToSize(PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);

pdfPage.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;

pdfPage.Width = size.Width;
pdfPage.Height = size.Height;
pdfPage.TrimMargins.Top = 0.5;
pdfPage.TrimMargins.Right = 0.5;
pdfPage.TrimMargins.Bottom = 0.5;
pdfPage.TrimMargins.Left = 0.5;
doc.Pages.Add(new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage());
XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
XImage img;
try
{
    img = XImage.FromFile(s);
    //pdfPage.Width = img.Size.Width;
    //pdfPage.Height = img.Size.Height;
    xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
    img.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    flag = 3;
    errormassage = ex.Message;
    errorfiles.Add(s);
}


xgr.Dispose();
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(s);
doc.Save(s.Replace(fi.Extension, ".pdf"));
doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload of `xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);` that has parameters for width and height and specify the values you need.

Your call draws the image with the size specified for that image - and the results are simply unpredictable.

The call `xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 595, 842);` will always draw the image in A4 size. Images with a different aspect ratio will be distorted. Calculating the image size to preserve the aspect ratio is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I don't know how to edit it.Could you tell me how to edit?

Comment: Code that always scales the image to A4 size was added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid image distortion while scaling you have 2 options.

1. you can scale the image size using the following function:

   ```
       static bool SaveImageAsPdf(string source, string destinaton)
    {
        try
        {

            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
            XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
            XImage img = XImage.FromFile(source);
            if (img.Height <= 842)//A4 height
                xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0); // don't scale
            else
            {
                double Scale = img.Height / 842.0;
                xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, (int)(img.Width / Scale), (int)(img.Height / Scale));//scale to A4
            }
            doc.Save(destinaton);
            doc.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {

            throw;
         }
    }
   ```
2. another option is to scale the pdf page size from its default A4 size. you can do this using this function:

   ```
      static bool SaveImageAsPdf1(string source, string destinaton)
    {
        try
        {

            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            XImage img = XImage.FromFile(source);
            PdfPage page = new PdfPage();
            if (img.Height > 842)
            {
                page.Height = img.Height;
                page.Width = img.Width;
            }
            doc.Pages.Add(page);
            XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
            xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
            doc.Save(destinaton);
            doc.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
   ```